# what is Unknown in react-native

Tags: react-native

I did not put any undefined variables in the view but it appear some Unknow tags,so I wonder what is Unknown there?

`<View>
       <View style={styles.row}>
         <Text>{rowData.user.name}&middot; {rowData.createdDate}</Text>
            <Text>{rowData.title}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.separator} />
        </View>`

in chrome I seen between the View and Text there is a Unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if this is due to text nodes in your code, specifically white space like tabs and newlines. Please see this issue from the react dev tools:

https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/44

There are several such issues on the devtools tracker, sometimes related to a lack of displayName on components but I don't see how that applies here.

Suggest opening an issue on the React Native Github tracker as I doubt this is expected. Someone on the RN team might be able to give us a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you define `Text` and `View`?

At the top of your file you should have something like this,

ES6

```
var {
  View,
  Text,
} = React;
```

ES5

```
var View = React.View;
var Text = React.Text;
```

Comment: That's not what they're talking about - he means that in the Chrome debugger it shows nodes labelled as "Unknown" as well as the ones he's explicitly defined.